# how to take assets from an external application folder in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, assets, src, vue-cli, webpack-file-loader

I have a folder with images and folder with vue-app(archy)

[image]

so i need to get in components those images
I tried something like this, but didn't succeed

```
<div v-if='photo' class="post-img">
  <img :src="`~@/../../uploads/posts/${photo}`" alt="img">
</div>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: How is those files being loaded by your application server? I mean, are they accessible like: `http://myserver:8080/somecontextfolder/uploads/posts/.....` ? Depending on it you can just reference the relative path for it.

Comment: client-app sends them to the server-app and server-app saves them in external folder, but how to get access to them i don't know

Comment: Have your server-app return you the url of the resource. You can't use the relative path directly because those are substituted at build time. You need a public url for the media

Comment: I tried to save in server the whole path, so i get something like this "../uploads/posts/3971de6a-3ef1-4b6f-b95d-5591cd6c42eb.jpeg" but i still have no access to it